# Cross-page silent interaction in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently doing a project and have run into a wall first up. I need to do the following:
1. Access a webpage (on the same domain) via JavaScript silently
2. On that webpage, navigate it by navigating via buttons
What I mean is, I need to (for example) press the 'Submit' button after changing a few value in a form on a page. However, all of this needs to be done 'silently'. As in, the client does not see any of this going on - it's all silent in the background. (I'll add some pseudo code below for clarity on what I mean)
I've got the two aspects sorted, it's just getting them connected that I need to work out. For 'accessing' the page, I am using the jQuery `$.get("url");` and for the interaction I planned to just use the returned object's `document` property.
I haven't found much information on this topic, so any help would be appreciated.

#### Important note

Because of the wise decisions of our organisation, and because all of the operations are behind a very heavy firewall, we use IE 11 as our primary browser for old system compatibility. Which means, we can use ActiveX. I haven't found much as to using ActiveX for this kind of purpose, however I thought it was important to note in case there were any solutions which used ActiveX.

#### Pseudo code

```
page_object = $.get(url)

page_object.document.getElementById("first-button").click();

// wait for that to finish

page_object.document.getElementById("input-1").change("Changed input");
page_object.document.getElementById("input-2").change("Changed input");

page_object.document.getElementById("form").submit()
```

### Responses to questions

It's for our internal systems, the other team is very frustrating about how they like to do things and they keep their systems as they like them (as in, they won't change it). My manager specifically asked for it to be done this way, not exactly sure why, so, unfortunately, the web scraping method is not possible.

#### Overview on what this is actually for

We use a ticketing system to manage our internal employees IT issues, let's call it Alpha for ambiguity. Alpha is a bit of a rigid system, and we do not have direct access to its API in order to post new tickets outside of the system. However, a higher level application team has created a ticketing web page which CAN post its own tickets, however the method they use means that we are unable to derive the methodology and apply it to our own scripts in an attempt to automate our services. So, instead of having our 'customers' (ie. internal staff who need IT assistance) go on the website, fill out the forms, download the fixes, we plan to just get them to click a button (or for us to direct them to a webpage) and it will a) Autofill all of the relevant information and perform any actions needed and, b) submit the ticket, send it off to Alpha and make sure it's all logged correctly. I have to make it clear, there are no 'illigal' activities going on here - and I wouldn't be silly enough to broadcast it on StackOverflow if I were. All of this is directly instructed by our application development team as a workaround until the API becomes available.

Comment: Can't you just send HTTP requests?

Comment: Selenium or other automation frameworks....

Comment: What kind of form is it? What is it about? Some context would be nice, because this approach may have legal implications.

Comment: I'd let the other team keep their stuff and ask them to send me the API for their backend so you can develop against that API, instead of trying to mess/deal with their markup.

Comment: Just gave some context above, Thomas :)

Comment: What about an simple iframe?

Comment: Ooh that's actually not a bad idea, I could instead tunnel through the iFrame and interact with it that way (hiding the iFrame, of course) and see if that works! I'll give that a go!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a headless browser. Not sure if there are any client side headless browsers... but if you can run nodeJS, one solution would be to use zomiejs.

After reading your comment it seems as though you have the relevant information to automatically fill out the form for your employees, so I would just create a simple webpage which automatically fills in a duplicate form of the one being offered by the other department. When the user submits the form, send a POST request to the server, the server will then use a headless client to interact with the other departments form and fill it in with the correct information, and then respond to the POST.

This however, seems like a really contrived method of accomplishing the task. The better way would just be to view the endpoint of the form that they are using and send data there, then handle the response.

Below is a snippet:

```
const Browser = require('zombie');

// We're going to make requests to http://example.com/signup
// Which will be routed to our test server localhost:3000
Browser.localhost('example.com', 3000);

describe('User visits signup page', function() {

  const browser = new Browser();

  before(function(done) {
    browser.visit('/signup', done);
  });

  describe('submits form', function() {

    before(function(done) {
      browser
        .fill('email',    'zombie@underworld.dead')
        .fill('password', 'eat-the-living')
        .pressButton('Sign Me Up!', done);
    });

    it('should be successful', function() {
      browser.assert.success();
    });

    it('should see welcome page', function() {
      browser.assert.text('title', 'Welcome To Brains Depot');
    });
  });
});
```